# Have ConstraintLayout with ScrollView stop at the top of the button in Android

Tags: android, scrollview, android-constraintlayout

I'm having a layout in which I sometimes have 2 buttons and sometimes 1 button on the bottom, outside a ScrollView. When I add `layout_marginBottom="60dp"` to the ScrollView, the ScrollView stops above the button, which is good. But sometimes the second button is visible and I don't want to change the `layout_marginBottom` programmatically. What is the correct way of doing this with a ConstraintLayout?

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="60dp">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingBottom="8dp"
                android:text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate eleifend tellus. Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu, consequat vitae, eleifend ac, enim. Aliquam lorem ante, dapibus in, viverra quis, feugiat a, tellus. Phasellus viverra nulla ut metus varius laoreet. Quisque rutrum. Aenean imperdiet. Etiam ultricies nisi vel augue. Curabitur ullamcorper ultricies nisi. Nam eget dui."
                android:textSize="26sp" />
        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    </ScrollView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:text="Button 1"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button2"
        tools:visibility="visible" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:text="Button 2"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Do you want to hide one button at a specific time?

Comment: the second button's visibility is enabled from a certain action in the app

Answer (score 0):

Never use *MATCH_PARENT* as a width or height with a child of *ConstraintLayout* since it may have unpredictable results. Use *MATCH_CONSTRAINT* (0dp) and make the constraints to the parent instead.

From the documentation:

> Important: MATCH_PARENT is not recommended for widgets contained in a ConstraintLayout. Similar behavior can be defined by using MATCH_CONSTRAINT with the corresponding left/right or top/bottom constraints being set to "parent".

As for the question, place the *ScrollView* and the two buttons in a vertical [chain](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/constraintlayout/widget/ConstraintLayout#Chains). The chain style should be `CHAIN_SPREAD` which, I believe, is the default.

I assume that the button that is sometimes there is made to disappear with its visibility set to `GONE`. You may need to look at gone margins to make the widgets position correctly when the widget is gone.

---

---

Like so:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingBottom="8dp"
            android:text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate eleifend tellus. Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu, consequat vitae, eleifend ac, enim. Aliquam lorem ante, dapibus in, viverra quis, feugiat a, tellus. Phasellus viverra nulla ut metus varius laoreet. Quisque rutrum. Aenean imperdiet. Etiam ultricies nisi vel augue. Curabitur ullamcorper ultricies nisi. Nam eget dui."
            android:textSize="26sp" />
    </ScrollView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:text="Button 1"
        android:onClick="onClick"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/scrollView2" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:text="Button 2"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button1" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Which gives this display:

[image]

and with button1 "gone":

[image]

Comment: When I do what you suggest, the buttons are not in the bottom anymore. They reside inside the ScrollView, which is not what I want.

Answer (score -1):

I'll answer my own question. It works with putting the Buttons inside a LinearLayout. So much for the "flat hierarchy".

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/buttonLayout"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingBottom="8dp"
                android:text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate eleifend tellus. Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu, consequat vitae, eleifend ac, enim. Aliquam lorem ante, dapibus in, viverra quis, feugiat a, tellus. Phasellus viverra nulla ut metus varius laoreet. Quisque rutrum. Aenean imperdiet. Etiam ultricies nisi vel augue. Curabitur ullamcorper ultricies nisi. Nam eget dui."
                android:textSize="26sp" />
        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    </ScrollView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/buttonLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent">


        <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:text="Button 1"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button2"
        tools:visibility="visible" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:text="Button 2"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp" />

        </LinearLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```